# reading only unique data pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge csv dataset with few columns. One of the column is 'Id'. I want to read only the unique values of the id from the CSV.  Is it possible to do so in pandas?

I only want the unique ids but i don't want to load the whole dataset in memory

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put all the content of your file in your memory at one point in time, there is no way around that. (how does your computer know where your IDs are on the disk, without loading them first?)

You can do this sequentially though, so it won't kill your RAM:

```
unique_ids = set()
csv_iter = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
for chunk in csv_iter:
    unique_ids.update(chunk['id'])
```